# Show and hide loading at the beginning and end of the observable subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, rxjs, angular2-observables

I want to show and hide the loading at the beginning and end of the observable subscription, but not succeeding. I think it's something related to `forkJoin` or `switchMap`. Below is what I've tried:

```
this.query
  .debounceTime(400)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap((query) => {
    // code...
    return Observable.forkJoin(sources);
  })
  .finally(() => console.log('completed')) // never called
  .subscribe((hashtags) => {
    // code...
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }, () => {
    console.log('completed'); // never called
  });
```

Comment: What version of rxjs are you using? 5+?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 5.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very common problem with `forkJoin` is that all its source Observables need to emit at least one value and complete before the `forkJoin` emits anything.

It's hard to say what you're doing inside `switchMap()` and what `this.query` is but both the `complete` signals and the `finally()` operator are called only when the Observable chain completes. So if you're receiving items in the `next` callback (that's the `(hashtags) => { // code... }` function) and you know the `completed` string is never printed that it seems like the source never completes and thus either `finally()` nor the complete callbacks are called.

Comment: I understood why it is not working, but how can I get around this?

Comment: It depends which one of the problems I mentioned you have

Comment: this.query is a Subject for a realtime search and inside switchMap I'm doing http calls.

Comment: So it's the second issue I mentioned. You could use `return Observable.forkJoin(sources).finally(...);` and place all your logic there. The `forkJoin()` completes right after it emits its only value so this `finally` will always be called.

Comment: It works partially. When you are searching, but the switchmap cancels the previous search and does another soon after, the loading does not work correctly.

Comment: Well, if you don't like what `switchMap` does then don't use it.